# Expectation of 2 r.v with imaginary $i$ in their sum

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $Z=\Omega \to \mathcal{C}$

,i.e

$X+iY$ with $X,Y:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ random variables.

Show that : $|E[Z] | \leq \mathbb{E}[|Z|]$
where $\mathbb{E}[Z]=\mathbb{E}[X]+i\mathbb{E}[Y]$

**My proposal**

We have $$Z = X+iY$$

Taking the amplitude of the imaginary leads to $$|Z| = \sqrt{X^2 +Y^2}$$.

Canonical Representation of a random variable :

Let $A_{j},$ partition of $\Omega$   and $a_{j}$  real numbers,  where $j=1,2,\dots,n$ , and now we have that : $$Z = \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{j} \mathbf{1}A_{j}$$

So $$ |Z(\omega)|  = \sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{j}| \mathbf{1}A_{j}$$

Therefore $$|\mathbb{E}[Z]| =| \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{j} P(A_{j})| = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \lvert a_{j} \lvert P(A_{j})=\mathbb{E}[|Z|] $$

I do not know if is correct.Any suggestion?Help?

Comment: I do not understand your canonical representation. Why $a_j \in \mathbb{R}?$

Comment: @P.J. By definition of the canonical representation of the random variable the $a_j \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Yes but that was when the random variable was real valued

Comment: @P.J.that’s why I switched to the amplitude

Comment: Yes that part is correct, maybe you should delete the first step after the words 'canonical representation'. Anyway, in your last statement, the second equality should be $\leq $ from triangle inequality

Comment: @P.J. $$|\mathbb{E}[Z]| =| \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{j} P(A_{j})| \leq \sum_{j=1}^{n} \lvert a_{j} \lvert P(A_{j}) = \mathbb{E}[|Z|] $$